# How to rearrange exponential equation when there is multiple instances of the same variable but not all are a power?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

So it's been a very long time since I've learnt any calculus, and any further reading just keeps confusing me further.

I have the ff eqn:

$$
y =\frac{x+300\times2^\frac{x}{7}}{4}
$$
I want to rearrange the equation so that the expression solves for $x$ instead. I looked into derivatives/logarithms but not quite sure how to proceed.

The equation above is an exponential curve to determine the xp ($y$) required to level up at every level $x$. So essentially it needs to be rearranged so that instead of plugging in the level and it telling me how much xp is needed, I can instead plug in the xp value and it'll tell me the level.

Comment: There may not be a closed form solution without using the Lambert W function

Comment: Do you need to solve it for *every* $y$? If you have a *particular* $y$, finding just *one* such $x$ is equivalent to fully solving it - because the function on the RHS is monotonically increasing - and for some $y$ maybe you can just guess the $x$.

Comment: Oh that's a good point sorry, let me edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: To emphasize and reiterate Henry's comment, just because a question is easy to write does not make it easy to solve.  In the case of questions like these, the answer often can not be written any more cleanly than the answer to the question ___ is "*the answer to the question ___.*"  In some cases we have a symbol for such a thing, such as asking to solve for $x$ in $y=\sin(x)$ we would say that $x=\arcsin(y)$.  That in reality is not far from just saying "the answer is '*the answer*'"... we just had to invent notation for it.  In your specific problem it is much the same.

Comment: We have to rely on the "[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)", a non-elementary function which has been named and is "*the answer*" to the question of solving for $x$ in $x\cdot e^x = y$.  It is not a pretty function.  It is not a function that is often used.  It is not a function that an undergraduate even really has reason to hear about in most circumstances, let alone learn about.  It is not expressible in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).  It is not easily used in calculations.